# How to show all terms with are used in Content?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have Content type: Products. It has field (Brand) on taxonomy base.
I use Views and want to see list of terms (all brand names) wich are used in my materials on the Product type base. I understand that it is possible to chose Taxonomy as base for Views building, but I want to build View on Content base.

Answer (score 9):

Is this in Drupal 6 or Drupal 7? In Drupal 7, you should create a content view, use fields, and then in the fields section and select the relevant content field. This should then display all the various options that are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version you're running but using Drupal 7 and Views 7.x-3.7+ something like this would work:

1. Add a new view for you custom content type.
2. In the views edit screen under `format` change `show` from `content` to `fields`.
3. Under `fields` click add and search for `Content: All taxonomy terms`. In the popup for the new field you can check `Limit terms by vocabulary` and select the correct vocabulary.

In your case you could use the actual field `brand` instead of `Content: All Taxonomy Terms`.

Answer (score -1):

I found that necessary point is using the Aggregation option; it will give only unique terms. The main point is taking out the "Sorting by date" option.